# Sort a String consisting of letters and numbers

Tags: c#, string

I have some strings, like below

```
a1
c1
b0
```

I want to sort them to `a1b0c1`

I tried the code below:

```
string answer1 = new string(answer.OrderBy(c => c).ToArray());
```

But the result is `011abc`

How to make the string `a1b0c1`?

Comment: What type is `answer` ?

Comment: Can you please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: And if you want to sort "c10" *after* "c2", then search for "Natural Sort"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, you have one string consisting of several lines. You have to split your string into an array, sort this and join the lines together:

```
string input = "a1\nc1\nb0";
string[] lines = input.Split('\n');
string result = string.Join("\n", lines.OrderBy(x => x));
```

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/u32Pk9